# App Inventor webview, prevent page not found

Tags: webview, app-inventor

I have  buttons that on click  open several pages in webview.
I have the option "FollowLinks" enabled.
And WebView.CanGoBack

My question is.
How "NOT" to open the default error page when there is no connection or the page was not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before using the webviewer, you can check for internet connection with the `web` component and the `Screen.ErrorOccurred` event, see [this example](http://www.appinventorblocks.com/appinventor-tutorials-tips/check-internet-connection).

While using the webviewer you can't check that. Therefore the default error page will be shown. Also if the page was not found, you will get the defined `404 page not found` error page from the server.